# Unable to use cout with a C++ string unless I run it through data() or c_str()

Tags: c++, cout

On the following program, I'm getting this when I attempt to use `cout` to output a C++ string to `stdout` - the other instructions produce the expected output.  I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows 7 system.

> First-chance exception at 0x00dd4e89 in Lab1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack
>   overflow. Unhandled exception at 0x00dd4e89 in Lab1.exe: 0xC00000FD:
>   Stack overflow. The program '[3740] Lab1.exe: Native' has exited with
>   code -1073741571 (0xc00000fd).

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

//more code here

int main() {

int number = 1;
string myStr = "Hello, string!";
cout << "number: " << number << endl;
cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
cout << myStr << endl;            //failing instruction

cout << "\nHit any key to continue...." << endl;
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

My instructor suggested changing the failing instruction to use `data()` or `c_str()` like so:

```
   cout << myStr.data() << endl;
```

I did this, and this resolved the problem.  He didn't know why, just said it worked so not to worry about it.

It seems to me that a C++ ostream object like cout should be able to handle a C++ string.  Am I missing something, or do I really need to use `data()` or `c_str()` with `cout`?

I also tried using `std::cout`, `std::string`, and `std::endl` - it didn't help.

Thanks in advance for your advice; I'm really wanting to understand what's going on here.

Helen

Comment: You need `std::string`, `std::cout` and `std::endl` unless there's something in `// more code here` or one of your header files that you are not showing us.

Comment: Post the relevant code. The piece you posted doesn't contain your error. Try narrowing it down into a self-contained, minimal example.

Comment: What is in "more code here"? I suspect it's significant.

Comment: Your code is fine, at least as posted.  You do need a `using namespace std;` unless you want to type `std::string`, etc.

Comment: There must be something else you're not showing us. The code you posted (after a couple minor fixups to get it to compile) will not have a stackoverflow.

Comment: I took out "#include <string.h>" and the problem was solved.  It was left over from an earlier assignment which used "char *"; this assignment required changing that to "string".\n  I did have "using namespace std;" but forgot to include it in my post.\n  The "//more code here" I commented out to be sure it wasn't being executed.\n  Thanks so much!  (Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to make a paragraph break, so I just typed it in.)

Comment: @Helen: that solution is actually *more* curious to me than your original solution of calling `c_str()`.  `string.h` should have  no impact on your code except to declare a bunch of functions you could call (but don't seem to).

Answer (score 3):

You should include `string` instead of `string.h`:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: It looks like she already has both `<string.h>` *and* `<string>` - the `<string.h>` needs to go of course.

Comment: I'd assume any downvote (I don't see any here at the moment)  was because it's not a particularly helpful answer - `<string>` is already included.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm pretty sure the original question only had <string.h> - invisible edits. However, that's the only reason I can think of for a crash.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore : I have voted down because he had there `#include <string>` whole time. But then I clicked "undo" cuz I realized that it 's something that can be easily overlooked.

Comment: @Luchian: I see.  But I would expect that without `<string>` the thing wouldn't build.  In any case, the OP has clearly left out some important information.

Comment: I took out the "#include <string.h>", leaving the "#include <string>", and the problem was solved!  Thanks so much!

Comment: @HelenWoodson: it's easier to "thank" by accepting the answer (and optionally upvote it)

Comment: @AndyT new user, I doubt he'll check SO again until he runs into another problem.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that `cout << myStr << endl;` was the troublesome line.

This code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    string s("Hello World!");
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did have "using namespace std;"

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that you have a stack overflow: it seems some function is being called recursively. You didn't define your own output function for `string` by any chance? What is in "more code here" which may be related to output operators?

Comment: I suspect it is related to pointing in the right direction ;-) The other problem descriptions just look so much easier to follow. While adding a comment: if the code in the file doesn't define a funny output operator, maybe "stdafx.h" does: this is local header as well, after all.